# How to do a reverse git submodule

Tags: git, symlink, git-submodules

I am having a structural problem with git. I have a repository (base repository) with common code which is used as a base for all my projects.

Each project has a different theme and modules which each has it's own repository (project repository).

It is not possible to put the project repository as a submodule in the base repository, because then we would have to change to submodule for every project and we wouldn't be able to push that to the base repository.

what WOULD be interesting, is to add the base repository as a submodule tot the project repository, because that wouldn't change for any project. Then I am stuck with the folder structure, because the the and modules are in a sub/sub/sub ... folder of the base code

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Comment: Uhm, yes, in each project repository, add the base repository as a submodule.

Comment: that would mean i need to set up the whole folder structure so that the theme ends up in the right directory?